# DSC HX300 and HP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Looking for XP Drivers for DSC HX300. On Sony Website says that Software (4.1 HomeMemories)is suitable for Windows XP SP3, but when download and run, it comes up with an error saying that it needs Vista as a minimum. Is this a bug in 4.1, or is the information incorrect and it does not run under XP? Is it possible to get an older version that does run under XP?

Answer (score 0):

**The quick answer is "No".**

Despite the ability to select Windows XP from the Drivers and Software site, the Play Memories page indicates Vista is the oldest OS supported.

[image]

There is no legacy support that I could find, so you may want to contact Sony Support to see if you can get it in a previous version.

There is activity related to this in the [Sony Community Forum](http://community.sony.com/t5/Cybershot-Cameras/Need-OLDER-version-of-Play-memories-home/td-p/437260), but didn't see any resolution.